# Error Code: 1271. Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION' on mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a view that is designed like this,

```
 SELECT ('header1,header2,header3,header' ) as `line` 
    UNION ALL 
 SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(column1,column2,column3,column4) as `line`
from mytables t 
  join table2 gc ON (gc.code = t.code)
where t.myfield = getId()
```

The *getId()* function looks like this,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `getId`() RETURNS varchar(30) CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    NO SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
return @bid$$
DELIMITER ;
```

In order to trace the error I went through a process of elimination where I recreated the view by dropping and adding the columns and the error happens when *column4* is added to the view.

The table definition for *table2* where *column4* is being taken from is,

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `code` int NOT NULL,
  `column4` varchar(100) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I am using the following query on the view *theview* (which is where *illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'* error appears),

```
SELECT distinct s.* FROM (SELECT @bid:='AB') parm, `theview` s;
```

I am using the getId() function on other views and I am not getting the error there.

Comment: 1st subquery in UNION uses server collation for a column whereas 2nd takes the collation from the table structure. They are not coercible it seems. Specify needed collation explicitly in the query with incorrect one. For example, ```SELECT ('header1,header2,header3,header' ) COLLATE {latin1_???} as `line` UNION ..```

Comment: Thank you @Akina ! Added collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci to the first query in the union and it looks like it is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per suggestion received to the question I added collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci to the first query, so the query now looks like,

```
SELECT ('header1,header2,header3,header' ) collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci as `line`
```

That looks like it has done the trick.

Comment: this solves my problem but I did not get the point of this change, great answer