# Why SQL injection UNION attack does not work?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I am trying to get the table names and other relevant information with sql injection. The idea was to use a sqli union attack, to get that information from information_schema and then get the content of the tables.

To achieve that, I fisrt try to get the number of columns the query was returning this way:

```
?parameter=111 or 1=1 union select NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL--
```

I reached the conclusion that the query was returning 4 columns(all of them are strings), and the next step would be to get that information like this

```
?parameter=111 or 1=1 union select group_concat(table_name),2,3,4 from information_schema.tables where table_schema=database()
```

But this does not work, if I remove the where clause it does not work either, or with other tables.

Is like when I add the "from" it stops working.

Why is this? How can I get the table names?

PD: I also tried

```
?parameter=111 or 1=1 0>ASCII(substring(SELECT table_name from information_schema.tables,1,1))
```

but it always return false, regardless the value of what value I compare it to.

Comment: "But this does not work" - If it's your own site, you should have access to error messages, as well as the generated SQL code. If you're attacking someone else's site, do you have permission to do so?

Comment: Yes, of course. This is a prepared machine to be attacked, so I dont have the logs

Comment: May be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65138947/error-code-1271-illegal-mix-of-collations-for-operation-union-on-mysql? Specifically, when I tried running a query like this `SELECT email, email, email, email FROM users WHERE id = 1 OR 1=1 UNION SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table_name),"test","test","test" from information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema=database();` I got an error `Error Code: 1271. Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'`.

Comment: You have to pick up a compatible collation in the same way as you pick up the number of columns.